# How to perform sequential API calls and avoid deep nesting with Spring WebFlux?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I'm using Spring WebFlux to make some asynchronous API calls. The problem is these calls need to happen in sequential order because each call depends on the previous one.

- Call C depends on call B
- Call B depends on call A

In the end, I need the values of all calls (A, B, and C) to create a response DTO.

In order to achieve this, I'm using nested flatMaps like so:

```
public Flux<PersonDto> getPersons() {
    return service.callA()
            .flatMap(dtoCallA -> {
                String name = dtoCallA.getName();
                String addressId = dtoCallA.getAddressId();
                service.callB(addressId)
                    .flatMap(dtoCallB -> {
                            String address = dtoCallB.getAddress();
                            String postalCodeId = dtoCallB.getPostalCodeId();
                            service.callC(postalCodeId)
                                    .flatmap(dtoCallC -> {
                                        String postalCode = dtoCallC.getPostalCode();
                                        return PersonDto.builder()
                                                    .name(name)
                                                    .address(adress)
                                                    .postalCode(postalCode)
                                                    .build();
                                    });
                        });

            });
}
```

How can I improve this and maintain the single-responsibility principle? These calls can't happen simultaneously. Should I use [context](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context) or [zipWhen](https://nickolasfisher.com/blog/How-to-Make-Sequential-API-Calls-and-Merge-the-Results-In-Spring-Boot-Webflux)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `context` but can you just rewrite the code?

```
Flux<DtoA> dtoA = service.callA();
Flux<DtoB> dtoB = dtoA.flatMap(dtoCallA-> ... );
Flux<DtoC> dtoC = dtoB.flatMap(dtoCallB-> .... );
Flux<PersonDto> = dtoC.flatMap(dtoCallC-> ... );
```

I suspect it will get compiled/optimized into the same byte code either way.

EDIT:

```
public class TuplePlay {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TuplePlay().run();
    }
    
    @Data
    @Builder
    static class Person {
        String a;
        String b;
        String c;
    }
    private void run() {
        Mono<Tuple2<String, Person>> sar = sa.get().map(s1->Tuples.of(s1, Person.builder().a(s1).build()));
        Mono<Tuple2<String, Person>> sbr = sar.flatMap(t->sb.apply(t.getT1()).map(s2->{t.getT2().setB(s2); return Tuples.of(s2, t.getT2());}));
        Mono<Person> scr = sbr.flatMap(t->sc.apply(t.getT1()).map(s3->{t.getT2().setC(s3); return t.getT2();}));
        scr.subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
    
    Supplier<Mono<String>> sa = () -> Mono.just("A");
    Function<String, Mono<String>> sb = s->Mono.just("B of " + s);
    Function<String, Mono<String>> sc = s->Mono.just("C of " + s);

}
```

Comment: And how will I get the values (name, address, and postalCode) from inside each stream? dtoCallA and dtoCallB holds name and address which are needed to create the PersonDto.

Comment: Yea. Tuples will do you, or an `Assembly` class.Personally I'd just change the specification. Seems like getting all this info at once it a typical use case.

Comment: Can you provide an example with tuples?